# Test-Path returns 'False' for network root directory

Tags: powershell, network-drive

I have a network drive at \\10.70.1.5 .  It has various sub-directories, but they change over time.  I want Powershell to check if the network drive is accessible.

In Windows Explorer I can view the directory, so I have access permission :

[File explorer directory view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFdj5.png)

When I attempt to run Test-Path on the network drive I receive a false even, however when I run Test-Path on a sub directory I get true.

```
PS C:\> Test-Path '\\10.70.1.5\'
False
PS C:\> Test-Path '\\10.70.1.5\e'
True
```

How do I test the network root directory to see if it exists / is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

The error is the same in both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.0 (rc2) *"... (Path) either does not exist, or it is not a folder."* It's clear to me that you're going to have to create a new PSDrive directly to a folder. I don't think you're going to come up with a way around it. It sounds like you'll need to have a directory at the root of your drive that *doesn't* change over time.