How can I avoid a memory leak when force killing PowerShell?
I'm making a Python script that creates shortcuts using PowerShell. I've taken advantage of the fact that if a network path isn't available it will take a long time to create the shortcut. I force kill the process if it takes too long, and this results in a bunch of shortcuts of available computers. Here is what's inside the loop
temp = "powershell; $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut(\"\"\"%cd%\\" + list[i][:list[i].find("\\")] + ".lnk\"\"\"); $Shortcut.TargetPath = \"\"\"\\" + list[i][list[i].find("\\"):-1] + "\"\"\"; $Shortcut.Save()"
subprocess.Popen(temp, shell=True)

This runs through a list that is like "COMPUTER1/insert ip here"
I then have another script that uses tasklist to find PowerShell processes and kills them after around 2 seconds. This works, but leads to a memory leak. I think it's a result of killing the PowerShell and the resources aren't released from RAM.
Is there a way to release that memory or avoid the leak altogether?

How do you know you have a memory leak?

The garbage collection only runs when the memory is needed.  If the memory leak is small, you may not see the GC remove the items.

If you run this in a loop, then yes.. you are bound to run into memory problems, since you keep creating COM objects, but never release them from memory.
After Shortcut.Save() you need to make sure the Windows Garbage Collector will remove them from memory using:
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WshShell)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Force killing scripts when a network path isn't available is also a bad idea..
Why not test a network path BEFORE trying to make a shortcut ?
That's what Powershell cmdlets Test-NetConnection and Test-Path are for.
B.T.W. Writing all that code in one long line is not only ugly, it also doesn't help in finding any mistakes you may have put in there.. Best write code in multiple lines with proper indentation.

I can't execute that after the .Save() because I've taken advantage of the lengthed time it takes to create a shortcut for an unavailable directory and I kill the process before it creates a shortcut to an unavailable directory. I know it's probably not a good way to test the paths but powershell, cmd, and python wouldn't detect the network paths. Is there a way to release it after I killed the process. Or is there a better way to do this in general

@KadenWarren Sorry, but that is nonsence.. You should stop killing the script with another script and instead make the first script better by testing the directory first and only if that exists create the shortcut. Then use ReleaseComObject on the objects you have created. Even better is that you let the PowerShell script itself loop over the list of COMPUTER1/insert ip here. That way you can create the WshShell COM object just once before the loop and reuse that inside the loop. Afterwards, you release it from memory. Once a script is killed, you cannot target the COM objects it created

I'll test the Test-NetConnection tomorrow, but I already tried Test-Path and it didn't work much like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60197342/27183856

While recommending in-process handling, which enables proper cleanup, is a good idea, note that your COM cleanup code by definition doesn't help here (it is never reached in the timeout scenario),
and wouldn't be necessary at all if the PowerShell process terminated normally (though in-session you may want to speed up release of unmanaged resources).
@Kaden: Have you tried Test-NetConnection -Port 445 -InformationLevel Quiet ...?

Thanks @mklement0 this was what I needed to get this working properly



uses tasklist to find powershell processes and kills them after around 2 seconds

In case you mean taskkill.exe: By default (unless /F is passed), it tries to cooperatively terminate a process, i.e. it gives the target process a chance to clean up before terminating and even allows it to refuse termination.
However, this cooperative mechanism only works with GUI-subsystem applications, whereas PowerShell is a console-subsystem application.
Thus, PowerShell does not get a chance to clean up, and while it seems that the managed part of its memory (the part managed by the .NET runtime) seemingly does get cleaned up, any unmanaged resources, including COM objects, are not released.
Note that PowerShell's Stop-Process cmdlet always terminates processes forcefully and therefore inherently bears the risk of memory leaks - see GitHub issue #13664 for a discussion.

It follows that you can't avoid memory leaks with your approach.

Therefore, you need an approach that handles timeouts in-process, where you can ensure proper cleanup, which also amounts to a much more efficient solution, given that you can use a single process:
The following sample code illustrates an approach that could work.
Note:

It relies on the PowerShell (Core) 7-only -Parallel parameter of ForEach-Object for running operations in parallel threads, surfaced as thread jobs via -AsJob, which allows termination of these threads on demand.

In Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1), you could:

Install the module that Start-ThreadJob comes with and use it to start individual thread jobs; e.g. with Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob

In a pinch, fall back to using - child process-based, slower and more resource-intensive - regular background jobs, using Start-Job



Caveat:

Unlike with normal termination of a PowerShell process, automatic release of unmanaged resources seemingly does not happen with thread jobs and background jobs as of PowerShell 7.4.x - even if not prematurely stopped with Stop-Job or Remove-Job -Force.

See GitHub issue #24549


Therefore, the solution below is only an option if the code that runs in jobs does not involve COM objects and other unmanaged resources (unless their manual release can be guaranteed); in the case at hand, you can use
Test-NetConnection -Port 445 -InformationLevel Quiet ... to test the (potential) availability of file shares on the target servers, which doesn't involve COM.




# Create sample input in the form of 'Computer1', 'Computer2', ...
$computersToTest = 1..5 | ForEach-Object { 'Computer' + $_ }

# Launch a parallel thread for each computer.
$jb =
  $computersToTest | 
  ForEach-Object -AsJob -ThrottleLimit $computersToTest.Count -Parallel {
    # Simulate a long-running network operation here; e.g.:
    #   Test-NetConnection $_ -Port 445 -InformationLevel Quiet
    Start-Sleep (Get-Random 6)
    $_
  }

# Check for computers that have responded within a specific timeout period,
# and act on only them.
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -le 2) {
  # Check for any output from the job's child jobs and act on it.
  $jb | Receive-Job | ForEach-Object {
    "Taking action for $_..."
  }
  # Sleep a little before checking for job output again.
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}

# Clean up. This will stop any child jobs that haven't finished yet.
$jb | Remove-Job -Force

Note:

The above uses a polling loop within the timeout period to check for results via Receive-Job, which is somewhat awkward.
However, it is the only way to ensure processing of job (thread) results as they become available:

While the Wait-Job cmdlet does have a -Timeout parameter, it produces no output until the entire timeout period has elapsed (and then outputs a job object describing the job that has completed rather than results).
Using -Any with $jb.ChildJobs as input  would by design only output one completed job once available.

While Receive-Job does have a -Wait switch too, it lacks a -Timeout parameter as of PowerShell 7.4.x; if such a parameter were added, timeout-based waiting that also streams results as they become available would become possible. Sadly, the feature request to that effect, GitHub issue #5433, was declined, on the grounds of perceived lack of interest in the community.





If you don't mind waiting for the timeout period to elapse in full and only then processing whatever results became available - even though they may have arrived earlier - you can combine Wait-Job -Timeout with Receive-Job as follows:
# ... job-creation code omitted; copy from above.

# Wait for the job(s) to complete, with a timeout.
$timedOut = $null -eq ($jb | Wait-Job -Timeout 3)

# Stop any child jobs that haven't completed yet.
$jb | Stop-Job

# See how many have completed.
$numCompleted = @($jb.ChildJobs.State -eq 'Completed').Count
Write-Verbose -Verbose "$numCompleted of $($jb.ChildJobs.Count) thread(s) completed within the timeout period."

# Process whatever results are available.
$jb | Receive-Job | ForEach-Object {
  "Taking action for $_..."
}

# Clean up.
$jb | Remove-Job

